# Quarto: Placement of python tables

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, quarto

I am using a .qmd document to write my thesis, which is mainly in Python. Now and then, I would like to present a preview of the data - in the most cases by `df.head()`. My problem is, that when using `df.head().style`, the data frame is floating somewhere in the pdf (`style` seems to be needed to quarto internally convert the table to a `kbl()` - in order to look nice).

In the quarto documentation I wasn't able to find any flags which can be set in order to avoid floating tables. I noticed that there is a flag for `#| fig-pos = 'h'`, but the equivalent for `tbl-pos` was not found.

I wish to write a pandas Dataframe as table without floating.

## Update

here the reproducible code for your convenience:

````
```{python}
#| label: tbl-ohe_example
#| tbl-cap: 'One-hot vectorization example'
#| tbl-column: body

(
    pd.DataFrame(
        data = {
            'Sentence': ['I like to eat apples', 'I like to eat bananas'],
            'Tokens' : [['I', 'like', 'to', 'eat', 'apples'], ['I', 'like', 'to', 'eat', 'bananas']],
            'Vector' : [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]],
        }
    )
    .style # Needed to convert df.head() to kbl format
    .hide_index() 
)
```
````

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible code example here to test?

Comment: @shafee any updates on your side? I have update the code with a reproducible example.

Comment: I have tried your code and the table is showing up in the right place. I would recommend giving a complete minimal example of a qmd file that showcases the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this issue is: Use `.to_latex()` from pandas, and add argument `position='h'`, use `output: asis` and print everything - see code example below:

```
#| label: tbl-ohe_example
#| tbl-cap: 'One-hot vectorization example'
#| tbl-column: body
#| output: asis

print(
    pd.DataFrame(
        data = {
            'Sentence': ['I like to eat apples', 'I like to eat bananas'],
            'Tokens' : [['I', 'like', 'to', 'eat', 'apples'], ['I', 'like', 'to', 'eat', 'bananas']],
            'Vector' : [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]],
        }
    )
    .to_latex(
        index = False,
        position = 'h',
        ... # place other arguments here
    )
)
```

I personally even used `tabularx` instead of `tabular`, which is feasible changing direct the string using `str.replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a similar answer to the one above [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/4849). But this lead to the issue that Quarto now disregards the provided table label and caption. I found a solution with the following set up:

```py
#| label: tbl-mytable
#| tbl-cap: This is awesome
#| tbl-pos: H

from IPython.display import display, Latex
display(Latex(df.to_latex(index=False)))
```

This places the table at the right position within the pdf document while also displaying the provided caption.